# addRoutePattern AXL error

Tags: soap, cisco-axl, cucm

When calling the addRoutePattern AXL API I get back the following SOAP response:

ENUM for TRUE not found in TypeStatus

I'm not sure what it's referring to as TypeStatus isn't a Key mentioned in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. `"useCallingPartyPhoneMask"=>"On"` On is the valid answer not TRUE. When in doubt build it by hand then use the Get API call to parse the result.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for all of these types of questions is to review the AXL WSDL and related files.

From the `AXLSOAP.xsd` schema file which you'd downloaded with the AXLToolkit, I look under `<xsd:complexType name="RRoutePattern">` and found the desired param:

`<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="useCallingPartyPhoneMask" type="axlapi:XStatus"/>`

This confirms that we need to check the `XStatus` ENUM in the `AXLenums.xsd` file.

This yields:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="XStatus">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Off"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="On"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Default"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

This quickly told me that the options you needed to send could have been:

- `On`
- `Off`
- `Default`